# How can I find the ID of my LinkedIn account?

Tags: linkedin

How can I find the (numeric) ID of my LinkedIn account when I have ***already set a public profile URL***?

#### Public URL setting

[image: Screenshot]

[The ID would part of the URL](http://www.ehow.com/how_10073058_linkedin-id.html), but it is not there now that I have a public profile URL. Is it somewhere in a settings page (I tried to look in "Privacy & Settings")? Or is there some other way to find it ***without changing the LinkedIn profile*** (as there is a risk of losing the already-assigned public profile URL - breaking links on other sites)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're logged in [image]

This will bring up a new URL in the browser which looks something like this.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=46036342&trk=hp-identity-name
```

In my case from the above URL, the ID is **46036342**

Comment: It may not seem so at first (perhaps one would expect the ID to come from a profile URL such as *https://dk.linkedin.com/pub/nils-færgeman/1/b7b/20* where a public profile URL has not been set), but you are correct: It is in fact the ID (at least what they are asking for at the profile settings page at http://www.codeproject.com/ where the origin of my question is)

Comment: Yeah! Glad that helped! :)

Comment: In my case its not the digits, its the combination of upper and lower case alphabates and the length is 39.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but could you show where exactly on the Profile you have clicked to go to the page/tab you show here?

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for the ID of a company page, for example, try clicking 'Manage Page' and then the ID numbers will be in the URL.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked